# Send keystrokes to a process on Console

Tags: shell, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, macro

If I have a terminal with a shell open, how can I write a shell script (any scripting language is ok with me!) that will send a keystroke to any one of the running processes?

As an example, how could I call a function that sends `Esc`,`:`,`wq`,`enter` to the Vim process, assuming I know its PID?

Is there an executable that could provide this API? Alternatively, could I do this with something like Tmux?

Answer (score 3):

If the vi process is executing in a tmux window:

```
tmux send-keys -t "${window_name}:${pane_number}" Escape :wq Enter
```

If you want to kill a vi process, send it a HUP signal. This doesn't save the file, but leaves file recovery data if not disabled in the vim configuration.

```
kill -HUP $pid
```